# Error: GraphQL error: Field 'metafieldsSet' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation' - Shopify GraphQL error

Tags: graphql, shopify-app

I have been recently playing with Shopify App Development and i'm struggling with a graphql call to amend some text. The image below displays the call being made correctly in the shopify GraphQL app which is where I test it.

[image]

However when I attempt to make this same call from the react component I get the following error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: GraphQL error: Field 'metafieldsSet' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation'
GraphQL error: Variable $metafields is declared by metafieldsSet but not used
```

Here is the react component in which I try and update the metafield

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { Layout, Button, Banner, Toast, Stack, Frame } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { Context } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
// GraphQL mutation that updates the prices of products
const UPDATE_TEXT = gql`mutation metafieldsSet($metafields: [MetafieldsSetInput!]!) {
    metafieldsSet(metafields: $metafields) {
      metafields {
        value
        id
        key
        ownerType
     
      }
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
    }
  }
`;
class UpdateTheText extends React.Component{
    static contextType = Context;
    render(){
        return(
            <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_TEXT}>
            {(handleSubmit, {error, data}) => {
              const [hasResults, setHasResults] = useState(false);
    
              const showError = error && (
                <Banner status="critical">{error.message}</Banner>
              );
    
              const showToast = hasResults && (
                <Toast
                  content="Successfully updated"
                  onDismiss={() => setHasResults(false)}
                />
              );
    
              return (
                <Frame>
                  {showToast}
                  <Layout.Section>
                    {showError}
                  </Layout.Section>
    
                  <Layout.Section>
                    <Stack distribution={"center"}>
                      <Button
                        primary
                        textAlign={"center"}
                        onClick={() => {
                          let promise = new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
                            const newmetafields = {
                                  key: "ExtraShopDesc",
                                  namespace: "ExtraShopDescription",
                                  ownerId: "gid://shopify/Shop/55595073672",
                                  type: "single_line_text_field",
                                  value: "This is an extra shop description twice"
                              }
    
                            promise = promise.then(() => handleSubmit({ variables: { metafields: newmetafields }}));
                          
    
                          if (promise) {
                            promise.then(() => this.props.onUpdate().then(() => setHasResults(true)));
                        }}
                      }
                      >
                        Update Text
                      </Button>
                    </Stack>
                  </Layout.Section>
                </Frame>
              );
            }}
          </Mutation>
        );
    }

}

export default UpdateTheText;
```

I believe i'm passing the variables into the gql but it doesn't seem to be picking them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh,

This all along was an API version issue. Shopify CLI still spins up Oct 2020 API. Metafieldset was only added in the 2021 API

https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/mutations/metafieldsset

The error messages threw me off

So to update just update the API version in server.js

```
API_VERSION: "2021-10",
```

Comment: Exactly, i was getting invalid id error. turns out i was using old version API and the operation that i wast trying is not supported.